# Two object arrays in nested foreach

Tags: php, variables, object

I have two variables:

- $foo - client1, client2, client3 (an object array)
- $bar - name, id, turnover (a string array)

If I echo `$foo->name` of client 1 it returns successful value, but:

```
foreach ($foo as $key1 => $value1) {

  foreach ($bar as $key2 => $value2) {

    echo $value2->$value1; // THIS IS NOT WORKING

  }

}
```

Hope I'm clear; I want to return these values:

```
client1's name
client1's id
client1's turnover
client2's name 
client2's id
etc...
```

This is successful:

```
foreach($foo as $client) {

  echo $client->name."<br>";
  echo $client->id."<br>";
  echo $client->billable."<br>";

}
```

returns client name, his id and if he's billable or not for every client. But the above code is not working. Name, id and billable are stored in a string thus:

```
$bar = array ([0] => name, [1] => id, [2] => billable )
```

Comment: Is `$bar` a string array? You mention it's an object, which wouldn't work.

Comment: Can you produce var_dump($foo, $bar); ?

Comment: A debugging tip: inside the first loop, do `print_r($value1)` to see if the outer loop is working.

Comment: (Aside: please do take the time to reply to comments that help you, and to thank people whose answers you accept `:)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace

```
$value2->$value1
```

With

```
$value1->$value2
```

If i understand you correctly example

```
$bar = array("name", "id", "turnover");
$foo = array(
        (object) array_combine($bar,range(1,3)),    //client 1
        (object) array_combine($bar,range("A","C")),    //client 2
        (object) array_combine($bar,range("X","Z")),    //client 3
);



foreach ($foo as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($bar as $key2 => $value2) {
        echo "Clients $key1 $value2 = ",$value1->$value2 ,PHP_EOL; // THIS IS NOT WORKING
    }
    echo PHP_EOL ;
}
```

Output

```
Clients 0 name = 1
Clients 0 id = 2
Clients 0 turnover = 3

Clients 1 name = A
Clients 1 id = B
Clients 1 turnover = C

Clients 2 name = X
Clients 2 id = Y
Clients 2 turnover = Z
```

Comment: Good spot, missed that one!

Answer (score 3):

Giving meaningful names to variables, and using curly braces access:

```
foreach ($clients as $i => $client) {

  foreach ($keys as $j => $key) {

    echo $client->{$key};

  }

}
```

Comment: +1 for meaningful names - very useful! Foo and bar are dreadful if used for real code (unless one has a collection of foos and bars, I suppose).

Comment: no this is just for example ofc I have meaningful names there.. but this seems to not work for me

Comment: Don't we deserve meaningful names? : D

Answer (score 1):

This is working:

```
$foo = array( "client1", "client2", "client3"); 
$bar = array("name","id", "turnover");

foreach ($foo as  $value1) {
    foreach ($bar as $value2) {
        echo $value1 . "->" . $value2 . "\n";
    }
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ebdba5ef40498d4ead4be9a281f715565717471a

I don't know where was your problem, I guess some typo.You didn't write what was your output and your code is half pseudo code (for example to concatenate  the two values you don't use ->). You should provide more details and more accurate code.

Comment: I realised it about the same time as you!

Comment: cannot convert object to string